# LLVM: How to convert some instruction/intrinsic into several chained instructions?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

Basically, suppose I have 3 instructions: `load $src`, `store $dest` and `modify`.

And I want to add an intrinsic/instruction `foo $x` that'd to something like

```
load $x
modify
store $x
```

Load and store just modify a special register that cannot be directly accessed.
The problem I'm facing is that for some reason the `Pattern<...>` in table gen that outputs multiple instructions doesn't compile and `Pat<...>` won't do since the instruction don't use each other result directly (i.e. the special register parameter is implicit), so I can't (or don't know how) create a single-node dag pattern from them.

So how do I solve this? I thought about turning into a pseudo instruction and lowering it to multiple instructions, but I'm not sure that the compiler will be able to optimize two consecutive `foo $x` into

```
load $x
modify
modify
store $x
```

that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do what I wanted by adding a special handling of intrinsic in MyTargetDAGtoDAG's `Select` method. I've replaced the given node by chained instruction nodes. But that solved the problem with code generation, I've yet to find the solution to the optimization problem.